# Converting array of object to en object with key : value dynamic

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects which look like this:

```
stuff = [
    { value: 'elevator', checked: true },
    { value: 'something', checked: false },
    { value: 'else', checked: true },
]
```

And I am trying to get something like this:

```
{
    'elevator': true,
    'something: false,
    'else': true,
}
```

All I can get since yesterday is an array of objects like:

```
[
    { 'elevator': true },
    { 'something': false },
    { 'else': true }
];
```

I tried with mapping on array and then using `Object.assign` but it's not working. I get the previous code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce`

```
var output  = stuff.reduce( (a,c) => (a[c.value] = c.checked, a) , {} )
```

**Demo**

```js
var stuff = [
    { value: 'elevator', checked: true },
    { value: 'something', checked: false },
    { value: 'else', checked: true },
];
var output  = stuff.reduce( (a,c) => (a[c.value] = c.checked, a) , {} )
console.log( output );
```

**Edit**

Using `object.assign`

```
stuff.reduce( (a,c) => Object.assign( {}, a, { [c.value] : c.checked })  , {} )
```

Comment: I'll try with reduce ! At lease, it's very clear working with this solution ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Iterate stuff array, So you will get each object under stuff. Then get that value that you need.

```js
var stuff = [
   { value: 'elevator', checked: true },
   { value: 'something', checked: false },
   { value: 'else', checked: true },
];

var obj = {};
for( var i=0; i<stuff.length; i++) {
  obj[stuff[i]['value']] = stuff[i]['checked'];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `reduce` function to make an single object from the given array. Just add your logic inside it. In this case, `value` to the property name and `checked` to it's value.

```js
const stuff = [
    { value: 'elevator', checked: true },
    { value: 'something', checked: false },
    { value: 'else', checked: true },
]

const mapped = stuff.reduce((obj, item) =>  (obj[item.value] = item.checked, obj), {});

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6, you can do it with `Object.assign`, `array.prototype.map`, some `destructuring`, `object litteral dynamic key` and `spread operator`:

```js
var stuff = [
    { value: 'elevator', checked: true },
    { value: 'something', checked: false },
    { value: 'else', checked: true },
];
var result = Object.assign({}, ...stuff.map(({value, checked}) => ({[value]: checked})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ok thx, It works great, I missed a level I guess and that's why I get the object I didn't want. Thank you mate!